# ASP + EF loading assembly problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I have a big problem. When I'm running asp SOMETIMES the application is craching with the following error message:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>   The types in the assembly 'Data.EF,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' cannot be loaded
>   because the assembly contains the
>   EdmSchemaAttribute, and the closure of
>   types is being loaded by name. 
>   Loading by both name and attribute is
>   not allowed.

Stack Trace:

> [MetadataException: Schema specified
>   is not valid. Errors:  The types in
>   the assembly 'Data.EF,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' cannot be loaded
>   because the assembly contains the
>   EdmSchemaAttribute, and the closure of
>   types is being loaded by name. 
>   Loading by both name and attribute is
>   not allowed.]
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection
>   objectItemCollection, Assembly
>   assembly, Boolean
>   loadReferencedAssemblies,
>   EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection,
>   Action`1 logLoadMessage) +480
>
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, EdmItemCollection
>   edmItemCollection, Action`1
>   logLoadMessage) +53
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, ObjectItemCollection
>   collection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
>   +93    System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
>   +130    System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ConstructContext()
>   +585    System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +76
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments,
>   DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
>   +21    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>   +143    Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformSelect()
>   +38    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
>   +74    Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.DataBind()
>   +363    Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.DataBind() +173
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
>   +66    System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   +75    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()
>   +102    Telerik.Web.UI.GridBaseDataList.get_Controls()
>   +33    Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxControl.PopulatePlainPanels(Control
>   parent, List`1 list, Control root)
>   +119    Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxControl.OnPagePreRender(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +1802
>   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +0
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs
>   e) +8864486
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
>   +103    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496

I also added LoadFromAssembly before every context call and still the same problem.

```
context.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(context.GetType().Assembly);
```

Enviroment: VS 2010, .NET 4.0, C#, EF

Could please somebody help me, to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards.

Comment: We have found a <a href="http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/80ae59ca-0785-44fb-8302-0a0505da2128/">similar topic</a> on MSDN forums, hope it helps.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving the same error on pages where there was a mixture of EntityDataSource objects and other data access such as ObjectDataSource and/or imperative code.

I took the advice of the MSDN article referenced in the other answer to your question.  I.e.  to use context.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(...).   I actually didn't know how to get a reference to the context instance used by EntityDataSource,  and I figured I should DRY it up anyway, so I created a partial class eg:

```
    public partial class YourTypeNameEntities
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(typeof(Full.Namespace.Of.YourTypeNameEntities).Assembly);

    }
```

It still didn't work, but I noticed fairly quickly that when calling DataBind() on a control bound to an EntityDataSource that my OnContextCreated() implementation was not firing!

That was a different issue to which I found a solution...   replace the ConnectionString and DefaultContainerName attributes in the EntityDataSource declaration with ContextTypeName.   For example:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="CountrySource" runat="server" 
ContextTypeName="Full.Namespace.Of.YourTypeNameEntities" EntitySetName="Country" 
OrderBy="it.Name" Where="it.Active==true">
```

That made sure my OnContextCreated implementation would fire and POOF,  the "Loading by both name and attribute is not allowed" problem went away!

Comment: I know this is old post. Can you please clarify where did you add this partial class?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but I've ran throught this problem twice this week and it seems to, in my case at least, to be related about the fact that I opened a VPN (for a complete other task with no link to this entity projet) and then, this error happened.

I've tried to close my VPN... then close my projet and re-open, completly close my VS without any success. But, restarting my computer make it works back.

Hope this helps if someone get this in same circonstences.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error message, using EF 5.0 and WCF Data Services 5.2.0.  This was a data service using a `DbContext`-derived class.

The fix for me was to separate code-first EF code from model-first EF code.  By moving the code-first code into a separate assembly, the error message went away and things are working.  The only way I was able to figure out to try this, is that the `[EdmSchema]` attribute exists on the code generated from our EDMX; but it doesn't exist on our model (code-first) code.

Hope that helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error for days. I using was a mixture of EntityDataSource objects and other data access such as ObjectDataSource in the same page. Replaced the EntityDataSource objects with ObjectDataSource. Problem went away!